# GridDB - Dynamically Adjust Hash Interval When Reaching Partition Threshold

Tags: griddb

As data in a cluster grows and partitions are created, there may be cases when the partition limit of 10000 is reached due to an interval that must be expanded. I want to put a trigger in place to check this on insert. Can the PARTITION_INTERVAL_VALUE / UNIT be re-assigned and partitions rebuilt to lower the number of partitions if the limit is reached?